# how to fix host name lookup failure error of sendmail

Tags: sendmail

When I run my web application which sends mail on my dev machine, the mail is not sent. The mail.info file shows that there was a host name lookup failure. How do i fix it? (i am trying to send mail to my gmail account.)

Comment: What OS is the machine running ?

Comment: ubuntu 8.04 is it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is something wrong with your server's dns settings or sendmail itself if it has separate dns settings. Make sure they are valid and alive.

Comment: how do i correct my server's dns settings?